# Godot 3.2.3 crashing on startup

Tags: godot

Godot 3.2.3 crashing on startup. It is running into issue

> Access violation - code c0000005

I only see the issue when I started godot using windbg without it I see a command windows pop up and disappear when I click in godot exe.
I started running into this issue after installing docker and other components that come with it. I did uninstall docker and WSL2 but it didn't solve the problem.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: If you would like report a bug you can do so at the [godot issue tracker](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues)

Comment: There is a possibly related fix: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/47368 - Please test the current [release candidate](https://godotengine.org/article/release-candidate-godot-3-3-rc-8). If the problem is present there, please open an issue.

Comment: godot 3.3 fail to run as well with the same error but godot 4.0 (current master) starts up successfully

Comment: Created issue: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/47734